# Proof that any finite field has prime power order

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

See the proof below.

I do not understand the sentence 'Viewing $F$ as a vector space over $Z/(p)$'.

How?

==============================================

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$F$ is already equipped with a multiplication $\mathbb{Z}/p\times F\to F$, so all that remains is to check the axioms for a vector space.

In general, whenever $R$ is a ring and $k\subset R$ is a subring that is also a field, $R$ is a vector space over $k$ in a natural way.